# XGBoost: Typical gamma and min_child_weight range

Tags: xgboost, hyperparameter-tuning, hyperparameter, boosting

What is the typical accepted range of gamma and min_child_weight parameters for the XGBoost algorithm?

Is the range of min_child_weight correlated with the number of feature or samples in the training dataset? Some of the available resources recommend setting this value to 1/sqrt(event_rate), what is the corresponding rule when training a regression model?

Comment: This article provides an overview of different recommendstions  https://machinelearningmastery.com/configure-gradient-boosting-algorithm/

Comment: @Sammy, while this article serves as a good starting point, it doesn't fully explain how to tune gamma and min_child_weight as function of the data characteristics (#samples, # features, data imbalance, etc)